# Removing Structures

Tags: matlab

I am programming a GUI and I have a variable structure like:

```
bin: 0.2000
Logical1: 0
Logical2: 0
Matrixraw: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
Matrixfiltered: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
Matrixcorrected: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
```

Every input file has its own matrix. In this case, we have two input files because every Matrix has two sructures. If we put 3 input files would be 3 structures and so on.

I want to make a button that given one index 1,2,3.. erases the i'th component from the Matrix structure. So, if you type 2 it will erase the second component of the matrix and would give:

```
bin: 0.2000
Logical1: 0
Logical2: 0
Matrixraw: {[1x1 struct]}
Matrixfiltered: {[1x1 struct]}
Matrixcorrected: {[1x1 struct]}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it.
Suppose you have this:

```
Matrixfiltered= {[1 2],  {}, 4}
```

and now we want to remove the second one:

```
Matrixfiltered(2) = []
```

Now you have this:

```
Matrixfiltered= {[1 2], 4}
```

Just give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a member of structure:

```
Matrixraw = struct('field1', 1, 'field2', '2')

Matrixraw = 

    field1: 1
    field2: 2

// delete first element of structure
Matrixraw(1) = []

Matrixraw = 

    field1: []
    field2: []
```

The syntax below will empty the structure and remove completely your variable data:

```
// both works
Matrixraw = {}

Matrixraw = []
```

Comment: but I only want to delete the structure corresponding to the index you decide.